# Formal character and unit

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characters

Denote by $\mathfrak{g}$ a complex semisimple Lie algebra and let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $U(\mathfrak{g})$ be the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.
Let $\Phi$
be the root system of $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h})$, write $W$ for the corresponding Weyl group of $\Phi$, and denote by $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ the root subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$ corresponding
to a root $\alpha$.
We fix a choice of positive roots $\Phi^+$, and let $\Delta$ be the corresponding subset of simple roots in $\Phi^+$. Note that each subset $I\subseteq\Delta$ generates a root system $\Phi_I\subseteq\Phi$, with positive roots $\Phi_I^+:=\Phi_I\cap \Phi^+$.

There are a number of subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}$ associated with the root system $\Phi_I$. Let 
$
\mathfrak{l}_I:=\mathfrak{h}\oplus\sum_{\alpha\in\Phi_I}\mathfrak{g}_\alpha
$
be the Levi subalgebra.
We note that once $I$ is fixed, there is little use for other subsets of $\Delta$. Therefore, we omit the subscript if a subalgebra is obviously associated to $I$.

Let $W_I$ be the standard parabolic subgroup generated by $I$. Let ${}^I W$ be the minimal length coset respresentatives of right cosets of $W_I$ in $W$.

Let $F(\lambda)$ be the finite dimensional simple $\mathfrak{l}$-module with highest weight $\lambda$.

For any $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module $M$ and for any $\lambda \in\mathfrak{h}^*$, let
$
M_\lambda := \{v \in M  :  h\cdot v = \lambda(h)v \ \text{for all $h \in \mathfrak{h}$}\}
$
be a weight space relative to the action of $\mathfrak{h}$. 
If $M_\lambda \neq 0$, then $\lambda$ is called a weight of $M$. The multiplicity of $\lambda$ in $M$ is defined to be $\dim M_\lambda$.

In general, any module in the category of weight modules having finite dimensional weight spaces can be assigned a formal character 
$
ch(M) := \sum_{\lambda\in \mathfrak{h}^*}
(\dim M_\lambda)e(\lambda).
$

Let $\Gamma$ be the set of all $\mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$-linear combinations of simple roots in $\Delta$. 
Denote by $\mathcal{X}$ the additive group of functions
$f : \mathfrak{h}^* \to Z$
whose support lies in a finite union of sets of the form
$\lambda - \Gamma$ for $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*$. 
The convolution product on $\mathcal{X}$ is given by
$(f * g)(\lambda) := \sum_{\mu+\nu=\lambda}
f(\mu)g(\nu)$.

Denote by $e(\lambda)$ the function in $\mathcal{X}$ which takes value $1$ at $\lambda$ and value $0$ at $\mu \neq \lambda$,
so that $e(\lambda) * e(\mu) = e(\lambda + \mu)$.

It is easy to check that $\mathcal{X}$ is a commutative ring
under convolution whose multiplicative identity is $e(0)$.

**My question:** Why $\sum_{w\in {}^IW} (-1)^{\ell(w)}chF(w\rho-\rho)$ is a unit in $(\mathcal{X},*)$, where $\rho$ is the half sum of positive roots in $\Phi$ and $\ell$ is the length function on $W$?